# Variable value changes automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I solved the assignment # 2 for the course "An Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python" at coursera.org. My assignment work OK according to specifications. However, when the user guess the number correctly and game restarts, one chance is automatically reduces. This is not happening when number of chances are exhausted. The logic for both conditions are same. Can anyone please explain and fix it.

Here is my code:

```
# template for "Guess the number" mini-project
# input will come from buttons and an input field
# all output for the game will be printed in the console

import simplegui
import random

# initialize global variables used in your code
secret_number=0
guess_counter=0
init_var = 1


# define event handlers for control panel

def range100():
    # button that changes range to range [0,100) and restarts
    global secret_number, guess_counter, init_var
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 100, 1)
    guess_counter = 7
    print ""
    print "New Game: The range is from 0 to 100"
    print "Number of guesses is ", guess_counter
    #print secret_number


def range1000():
    # button that changes range to range [0,1000) and restarts
    global secret_number, guess_counter, init_var
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 1000, 1)
    guess_counter = 10
    init_var = 2
    print ""
    print "New Game: The range is from 0 to 1000"
    print "Number of guesses is ", guess_counter
   #print secret_number

def get_input(guess):
    # main game logic goes here 
    global secret_number, guess_counter
    user_guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was", user_guess
    if user_guess > secret_number:
        print "Higher!"
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
        print "Lower!"
    else:
        print "Correct ... You WIN!"
        initialize()


    guess_counter -= 1
    if guess_counter == 0:
        print "You Lost, all guesses are consumed"
        initialize()
    else:
        print "Number of remaining guesses is ", guess_counter

def initialize():
    #restart the game, when all the guesses are exhaust
    if init_var == 1:
        range100()
    else:
        range1000()

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess the number", 300, 200)

# register event handlers for control elements
frame.add_button("Range is [0, 100]", range100, 200)
frame.add_button("Range is [0, 1000]", range1000, 200)
frame.add_input("Enter a guess", get_input, 200)

initialize()

# start frame
frame.start()

# always remember to check your completed program against the grading rubric
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i reassign the value in range100()  and range1000(). Will it not reset the guess_counter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a return under initialize()

```
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
    print "Lower!"
else:
    print "Correct ... You WIN!"
    initialize()
    return
```

Comment: Thanks, it really worked. Can you give a short explanation of this please

Comment: Once the person wins you were calling the initialize() function, and then continuing through the rest of the get_input function you were in.  By adding return on the next line it will not continue with the rest of the get_input function you were in.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I understood it now.